# how to stop a timer with repeats:YES

Tags: ios, timer

i have a "segment control" assigned to a function with 2 timers

one with repeats:NO and one with repeats:yes

i want to, when my segment is on position "0", the timer is on repeats:NO

and when my segment is on position "1", the timer is on repeats:YES

but if i put my segment in position "1" my timer **never stop**..

my function :

```
-(IBAction)sendFocusLiveBtn{
if(liveManual.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(sendFocusLive) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
if (liveManual.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(sendFocusLive) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

}

how to stop it?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(sendFocusLive) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

by itself, ***save*** the timer in a property (or ivar) like this:

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(sendFocusLive) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and then you can do:

```
[self.timer invalidate];
```

wherever and whenever you are ready to truly stop that timer.

Comment: If will not use timer any more, set timer property to nil. [self.timer invalidate]; self.timer = nil;

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MichaelDautermann's answer, you should change the selector to `sendFocusLive:` (note the colon at the end) and declare that selector as:

```
- (void)sendFocusLive:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    // Here you can test that timer == self.timer to ensure the right timer has triggered this method
    // And you can call [timer invalidate] here when required
    // It's a good idea to set timer to nil after you invalidate it
}
```